# create a distinct model option in a dropdown using django

Tags: python, django

I have created this application but the problem I face now is one that has kept me up all night. I want users to be able to see and select only their own categories when they want to create a post. This is part of my codes and additional codes would be provided on request

**category model**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1,related_name='categories_created')
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique= True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
```

**post model**

```
class Post(models.Model):
     user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1,related_name='posts_created') #blank=True, null=True)
     title = models.CharField(max_length = 120)
     slug = models.SlugField(unique= True)
     category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category_created', null= True)
```

addition codes would be provided immediately on request. Thanks

**View.py in post app**

```
def create(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        messages.error(request, "Kindly confirm Your mail")
        #or raise Http404
    form = PostForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None)
    user = request.user
    categories = Category.objects.filter(category_created__user=user).distinct()
    if form.is_valid():
        instance = form.save(commit=False)
        instance.user = request.user
        instance.save()
        create_action(request.user, 'Posts', instance)
        messages.success(request, "Post created")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(instance.get_absolute_url())
    context = {
        "form": form,
    }
    template = 'create.html'
    return render(request,template,context)
```

**Form**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = [
            "title",
            "content",
            "category",
        ]
```

**html**

```
{% if form %}

  <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy|safe }}
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Publish">
  </form>
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to add a field to your Category model so it's associated with a specific user. If that doesn't help you may need to provide more information as to what is going wrong in your view.

Comment: Can you share the code that renders the actual form view. It looks like the view you shared is the POST handler.

Comment: I added a user field in my category model but it still shows all the categories irrespective of the logged in user

Comment: @amacf I added it and updated the question. Kindly check it out

Comment: What happens if you change `Category.objects.filter(category_created__user=user)` to `Category.objects.filter(user=user)`?

Comment: it is still the same thing. `categories = Category.objects.filter(user=user)` is not referenced in the form. That is where I think the problem is coming from but I dont get it

Comment: Thanks it has been solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is well-described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform). Basically, you are using ModelForm which generates the form from your model. Your model doesn't know anything about filtering by user, so you will need to explicitly add a QuerySet to your form that only shows the desired categories. Change your "categories = ..." line to something like:

<strike>form.category.queryset = Category.objects.filter(user=user)</strike>

```
form.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(user=user)</strike>
```

Comment: `'PostForm' object has no attribute 'category'` I got that error

Comment: Okay try this: form.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(user=user)

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)

Comment: hope you dont mind if I ever have to come to this question to get your attention to a question in the future?

Comment: Ha, sure. If it's something new though, make a new question and just link it here.

Comment: I really appreciate that.

Comment: Hi kindly help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348817/django-polls-with-autentication thanks