# Django polls with autentication

Tags: django

I have a poll app using django from the docs. I now want to make it advanced. I dont want a user to be able to vote twice that means the users can only vote once else it would show an error message. It works fine if it is the super user that is logged in but for any other user, they are still able to vote multiple times.

**Model**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='question_created')
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text


class Choice(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,related_name='choice_created')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text
```

**View**

```
def vote(request, question_id):
    question = get_object_or_404(Question, pk=question_id)
    if Choice.objects.filter(question_id=question_id, user_id=request.user.id).exists():
        context = {
                'question': question,
                'error_message': "Sorry, but you have already voted.",
                }
        template = 'polls/detail.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
    try:
        selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        context = {
                'question': question,
                'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
                }
        template = 'polls/detail.html'
        return render(request, template, context)
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve with the `try..except..else` statement?

Comment: so that user can not submit empty form

Comment: I was especially referring to the `else` block, why is it part of the `try..except`?

Comment: increment the number of votes by one once a user votes

Comment: I think you can simply write `selected_choice.votes += 1` and the code from that indentation level within the `def` block, not the `else` block. It will be executed only if he `try` statement succeeds, since if it doesn't you return in the `except` statement. Can you try that?

Comment: so? is it working?

Comment: No. I do not quite understand. maybe if you present it as an answer I could implement it better and I could mark as correct if it works

Comment: Try to add 2 underscores like this "question__id" and "user__id" that's why the 'if' statement returns false every time and it lets you vote twice

Answer (score 0):

Try to move the `try: Except:` inside the `else:` statement.

add 2 underscores to "`question_id`" and "`user_id`" like this `Choice.objects.filter(question__id=question_id, user__id=request.user.id).exists()` maybe that's why the `if` statement returns false every time and it lets you vote twice

Also just for safety, you can change `selected_choice.votes += 1` to `selected_choice.votes = 1` you want to ensure that each record doesn't exceed more than one vote.

Hope it helped!

Comment: question__id & user__id are not necessary. using saved related id in a table itself is better most of the time.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your try block won't work as intended because `question.choice_set.get` wouldn't raise an exception if choice being empty and just returns `None`.
You can use if condition like:

```
 if selected_choice is None:
```

and for your main issue you should prevent unauthenticated users in your view like:

```
if not request.user.is_authenticated:
```