# geodjango with mysql database

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am developing an application with geodjango and I have been running into some difficulties. following the procedures on the official django website https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/#use-ogrinfo-to-examine-spatial-data . I first used the `orginfo` to check spatial data I got a failed message

```
FAILURE:
Unable to open datasource `world/data/TM_WORLD_BORDERS-0.3.shp' with the following drivers.
```

then I followed the remaining process creating the models and the error I got when I ran migration was

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/src/geolocation/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db import models
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.aggregates import *  # NOQA
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/aggregates.py", line 1, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import ExtentField
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .fields import (  # NOQA
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 4, in <module>
    from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSException, GEOSGeometry
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    HAS_GEOS = geos_version_info()['version'] >= '3.3.0'
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/geos/libgeos.py", line 196, in geos_version_info
    raise GEOSException('Could not parse version info string "%s"' % ver)
django.contrib.gis.geos.error.GEOSException: Could not parse version info string "3.6.2-CAPI-1.10.2 4d2925d6"
```

.

further codes would b supplied based on request. Kindly help with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Could not parse version info string* error is the issue in [ticket 28441](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28441), which has been fixed in Django 1.11.5.

Note that it's always a good idea to use the latest point release (currently 1.11.5 for 1.11.X) to make sure you've got the latest security patches and bug fixes.

Comment: I went through it and didnt understand the fix. it was very scattered. I use django 1.11. if you could edit your answer and give the fix I would be very very grateful I used `brew switch geos 3.6.1` and got error `Error: geos does not have a version "3.6.1" in the Cellar.
Versions available: 3.6.2` then I changed the version but that still didnt fix it.

Comment: You don't have to understand the fix or switch to geos 3.6.1. Just upgrade to Django 1.11.5.

Comment: the error message is different now. `AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'` how do I fix this . I am running on mysql database

Comment: Make sure you have `django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql` in your `DATABASES` setting. If that doesn't fix the problem, then please ask a new question, since it's a separate issue.

Comment: what would I assign it to because this is my `database` `'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'arbithub',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553400/geodjango-with-mysql-not-migrating kindly check it out

Comment: Hi @Alasdair kindly help check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348817/django-polls-with-autentication?noredirect=1#comment79739118_46348817

Comment: This fixed my issue. I was using django with mysql on Ubuntu 18.04 and after updating from django 1.11.4 to 1.11.13, everything is fine.