# geodjango with mysql not migrating

Tags: mysql, django

I am working on geodjango and just got an issue here [geodjango with mysql database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46552174/geodjango-with-mysql-database#46552265) resolved. When I ran migrate I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 364, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 356, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 62, in _run_checks
    issues.extend(super(Command, self)._run_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/model_checks.py", line 30, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1283, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 1358, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 219, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 322, in _check_backend_specific_checks
    return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/validation.py", line 49, in check_field
    field_type = field.db_type(self.connection)
  File "/Users/Olar/Desktop/arbithub/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 126, in db_type
    return connection.ops.geo_db_type(self)
AttributeError: 'DatabaseOperations' object has no attribute 'geo_db_type'
```

This is my database settings

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'arbithub',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

further codes would be supplied on request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the [spatial backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#module-django.contrib.gis.db.backends) in your `DATABASES` setting.

For MySQL, replace

```
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
```

with

```
'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql',
```

Comment: Thanks so much. If I have any other question I would reference it here

Comment: Hi  kindly help check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46348817/django-polls-with-autentication?noredirect=1#comment79739118_46348817

Comment: @king please don't message me to ask me to look at different questions

Comment: I asked the question awhile and have not got a perfect answer so I felt you could be of help.