# Django Database Migration

Tags: python, django

Hi have a django project a full project now I want to migrate to mysql from the default Sqlite3 which is the  default database. I am on a Mac OS and I don't know how to achieve this process. Any one with a complete guide on how to make the switch would be appreciated.

Comment: You should have read Django documentation before coming to SO.

Comment: I read the docs and didn't understand it. Where would you have me go to?

Comment: I seriously don't understand why people would down vote the question. It's not a crime not to understand docs and ask here

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project's settings file and edit DATABASES with proper database connection

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 
        'NAME': 'DB_NAME',
        'USER': 'DB_USER',
        'PASSWORD': 'DB_PASSWORD',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Now open mysql and create database as you give in DATABASE settings.

Go to your project -

./manage makemigrations

./manage migrate

This will create all the tables in the specified database name.

Comment: No need to run makemigrations, since presumably they would already have been created for the sqlite version.

Comment: I downloaded mysql to my MacBook. I don't know where to create the username or anything of those things.

Comment: Unlike apache saver where I just run MAMP and configure all. How do I configure this?

Comment: Which operating system you use?

Comment: I use a  Mac operating system

Comment: Hi. I use mac operating system

Comment: Hi, I believe you have mysql root password, you have to create one while installing mysql. Use "mysql -u root -p -h localhost" to start mysql, then you can create database with "create database testsample". In django settings for DATBASES change NAME="testsample", USER="root", HOST="localhost". That should work.